# Integer as array name in string array

Tags: android, xml

how can we strore integer as name in string array.i have to put numbers in my project.

here is my array.xml

```
<string-array name="1">
 <item>kN</item>
 <item>μg</item>
 <item>mg</item>
 <item>g</item>
 <item>kg</item>
</string-array>
```

thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#IntegerArray

Comment: what you want to store?

Comment: i want to store values from 1-20... so that according to index position we can extract value from another array.

Comment: when i save this..R. java save it as-> public static final int 1=0x7f040001;which shows error

Comment: @Raghunandan:i just want to store name as integer..list item will b string or symbols...so <integer-array> not worked in that case.

Comment: @gbl i am confused.not sure what you want and what does <integer-array> not worked in that case mean?

Answer (score 2):

The name must be a valid java identifier, because it is used in the generation of the R.java file.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8

Typically, it cannot be (or start with) a number, and it cannot be `true`, `false`, `null`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use integer for name because later it will be converted into a variable name in R.java and a variable name in java can start only with $ (dollar sign), _ (underscore) or with any alphabet.

So instead of using `<string-array name="1">` you can use `<string-array name="_1">` or `<string-array name="$1">`  or `<string-array name="a1">`